# CORS error despite changing Access-Control-Allow-Methods with CORS middleware when deployed in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, cors

I'm running one client local server with "VSC's Live servers" on localhost:5500, and I'm running a remote server using heroku.

Here is the relevant code regarding the AJAX call client-side when submitting a form:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "https://git.heroku.com/morning-falls-52888.git");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xhr.send(JContactRequest);
      xhr.onload = () => {
        const status = xhr.status;
        if (status >= 200 && status < 300 ) {
          $("form").append("<p id='submit-message' style='text-align:center;'>Thank you for your submission!</p>");
        } else if (status == 418 ) {
          window.alert(`Error: ${xhr.status}\nCannot brew coffee, I am a teapot.`);
        } else {
          console.log(`Before append ${status} ready state: ${xhr.readystate}`);
          $("form").append("<p id='submit-message' style='text-align:center;'>Submission Failed</p>");
          console.log(`After append ${status} ready state: ${xhr.readystate}`);
        }
      }
```

And here is the code server side:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const PORT = process.env.PORT ||4500;
const cors = require("cors");


app.use(cors());

app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Listening on PORT: ${PORT}`) });

// app.use((req,res,next)=>{
//   res.status(404).send('this is working');
// })

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.status(201).send();
  console.log("received get request");
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  var body=req.body;
  console.log(body);
  
  for(let [key,value] of Object.entries(body)){
    if(value==""){
      res.status(400).send(`Empty Field in ${key}`);
      res.end();
      break;
    }
  }
  var email = body.emailfield;

  if (body.comment == "Can you brew coffee?") {
    res.status(418).send();
  } else {
    res.status(200).send('message sent');
  }
  // calling the api
  const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  const msg = {
    to: email,
    from: 'd@gmail.com', // Use the email address or domain you verified above
    templateId:'*************************************',
    dynamic_template_data:body,
  }
  //ES6
  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {}, error => {
      console.error(error);

      if (error.response) {
        console.error(error.response.body)
        console.log(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
      }
    });
});
```

The message I'm getting on my console is the following:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://git.heroku.com/morning-falls-52888.git' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm kind of stumped because I would have thought that app.use(cors()) would have access-control-allow-origin=*.

I'm still very new to this, so any help is mighty appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT** I just wanted to add that this code was running fine when I was running the server locally on port 4500

Comment: You can ty to move `app.use(cors))` above `app.use(express.json())` and its importing `const cors = require('cors')` right below `dotenv` require

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> xhr.open("POST", "https://git.heroku.com/morning-falls-52888.git");
> ```

You're making an HTTP request to Heroku's Git repo, not to your application running on Heroku (which will have a URL like `https://APPLICATION_NAME.herokuapp.com/something`)

The CORS permissions have to be granted for the URL you are making the request to, not one that is loosely adjacent to it.